# Edit the link to accept the id of category and the number of page

Tags: php, mysql

I use below link to open the category

```
 onclick="location.href = 'categories/topics_categories.php?id=13';"
```

and i use below link to make paging to my pages

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
  echo "<a  href='topics_categories.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
        }
```

I want edit the link to accept the id of category and the number of pages , any ideas ?

Comment: what about `topics_categories.php?id=13&page=1` !?

Comment: thanks @xander it's work , make the answer in reply to confirm it's correct answer

Comment: there you go, also added a simple explanation or just research "url query string"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple parameters to the url query string with an ampersand sign (&), only the first field name has to be prefixed with a question mark (?):

In your case

```
topics_categories.php?id=13&page=1
```