# $_GET not working in header location

Tags: php, mysql

i use $_GET to get the categories id and it's works but when i add it to the header location it's doesn't appear any thing , The code :

```
if(isset($_POST['topicId'])){
    $id = $_POST['topicId'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id = ?");  
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute(); 

    $categoryId = $_GET['id']; 
    header ("Location: topics_categories.php?id=".$categoryId);
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();   
}
```

and the links appear like this :

```
    topics_categories.php?id=
```

It's doesn't appear anything after the id=

Comment: Can you confirm there is data in `$categoryId` ? echo it out to make sure

Comment: you're trying to create an infinite loop from nothing. It's just bouncing back and forth trying to figure out "what" should be its value.

Comment: Your code should work, as long as there is already an ID in the URL - if there isn't any, it won't show any either. You will need to show the complete code - for instance, where does the `$_GET['id']` come from?

Comment: Are you loading the initial page with an `id` GET parameter (`page.php?id=1`)?

Comment: in any which case => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and if that shows you a headers sent; you'll know what to after.

Comment: i will edit the code to see it

Comment: `var_dump($_GET['id']);` what does that show? if nothing, then it's not set/is empty/no value. Again; [what I said earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903770/get-not-working-in-header-location#comment74841596_43903770).

Comment: yes @ObsidianAge

Comment: @Fred-ii- when i put it before If statements it's show category id example '13' but inside the if it's now show anything

Comment: side note, dont call code after header location, it may or may not run. do use exit(); afterwards.

Comment: thanks @nogad for this note

Comment: if this has anything to do with your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/43890758/1415724 then you're probably trying to send a JS method to PHP, which won't work. You need ajax for this. The question's unclear. Or did you change methods? also make sure that `if(isset($_POST['topicId']))` is set and contains value. If you say the GET array doesn't work inside that conditional statement, then you may have a variable scope issue. That's all that comes to mind for me. Use error reporting with the link I gave you and make sure the query does execute. Add `exit;` after header also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes it's execute and the row delete but after delete the row i want it to return to same page

Comment: what's happening is when you submit the form the second time, only the topicId is there, nothing else. on the page I would add a hidden input that just contains the categoryId, so when the page loads the first time it will be `<input name="categoryId" value="<?php echo @$_GET['categoryId']; ?>"`

Comment: Thanks for you @DerekBaxter it's work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make an answer out of my comment,

What fixed it was the `categoryId` wasn't being carried on the second form submit.

To fix that, you put a hidden input field:

```
<input name="id" value="<?php echo @$_GET['categoryId']; ?>"
```

therefore it will be set the first time, and carry over on the second form submit.